# Reference variable based on another variable

Tags: terraform, kops

In `file1.tf` (generated by [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops)) I have a resource like this:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "my-vpc-tf-id" {
...
}
```

The resource ID was dynamically generated by kops and also added to `terraform.tfvars` (so it can be used in other places in the `.tf` files):

```
my_var = "my-vpc-tf-id"
```

Now I would like to reference the VPC resource from `file2.tf` without hardcoding its name:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "db" {
  ...
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.${var.my_var}.id}"
  ...
}
```

but Terraform complains that the `${var.my_var}` is not allowed. So instead I define this in `file2.tf`:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "db" {
  ...
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.{{MY_VAR_VAL}}.id}"
  ...
}
```

and I use `sed` to replace the placeholder with the value. This works well but complicates certain other tasks so I was wondering if there were other ways of achieving this without using `sed` or hardcoding the `my_var` value (just Terraform's HCL).

Comment: Generating a file with a varible resource name is not the intended way to use terraform. The names within terraform should be logical and fixed. Unfortunately, you are bound to this due to your usage of kops. The `sed` workaround seems to be best in this case. Maybe open an issue with kops and describe your problem there?

Comment: Markus's comment is correct, per https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18456. Unfortunately the workaround described there does not seem applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this is to use [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html) to look up the thing you want to refer to.

The [VPC data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/vpc.html) allows you to filter based on a number of different things but a typical one is to use the `Name` tag:

```
data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
  tags {
    Name = "${var.vpc}"
  }
}
```

And then you can refer to this VPC with:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "db" {
  ...
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.selected.id}"
  ...
}
```

Comment: If the VPC is to be created during the same run, this could lead to problems, since the data source is not dependend on the VPC and thus, the information is [being fetched upon state refresh](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html#data-source-lifecycle). At this point, the VPC is not yet available.

Answer (score -1):

The two cases are

(i) if they are both vpc and security group are in same run
we can directly refer vpc id in security group without any data sources

```
resource "aws_security_group" "db" {
  ...
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.my-vpc-tf-id.id}"
  ...
}
```

(ii) if they are run differently (using same remote state files or importing config)
use data source as mentioned above by ydaetskcoR

Comment: As stated by Oliver, the resource is not named `my-vpc-tf-id`, but rather some variable name (e.g. `vpc-47384-33234`). The name is stored in a varible called `my_var`.

Comment: what iam trying to say here is we dont need to store it in any variable if it is in single run.